# What is the HQL equivalent of the following SQL?

Tags: sql, hql, intersect

Below is the SQL running properly on the SQL server 2008.

```
SELECT ITEM_NO 
FROM 
    PROPERTY_VALUES
WHERE
    (PROPERTY_NAME ='Fax' AND  PROPERTY_VALUE = '123-123-123')

INTERSECT

SELECT ITEM_NO 
FROM 
    PROPERTY_VALUES
WHERE
    (PROPERTY_NAME ='Email' AND  PROPERTY_VALUE = 'testemail@gmail.com')

INTERSECT

SELECT ITEM_NO 
FROM 
    PROPERTY_VALUES
WHERE
    (PROPERTY_NAME ='Mobile' AND  PROPERTY_VALUE = '9844808631')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the SQL as follow, and the HQL should be obvious:

```
SELECT ITEM_NO 
FROM 
    PROPERTY_VALUES a, PROPERTY_VALUES b, PROPERTY_VALUES c
WHERE
    (a.PROPERTY_NAME ='Fax' AND  a.PROPERTY_VALUE = '123-123-123')
   AND
    (b.PROPERTY_NAME ='Email' AND  b.PROPERTY_VALUE = 'testemail@gmail.com')
   AND
    (c.PROPERTY_NAME ='Mobile' AND  c.PROPERTY_VALUE = '9844808631')
   AND
    (a.ITEM_NO = b.ITEM_NO AND a.ITEM_NO = c.ITEM_NO)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. What if the number of properties increase e.g. in above case I had three properties email, fax and mobile but there can be many more such properties. Please advise.

Comment: I guess you have to join it multiple times. I can't think of anyways doing that in HQL.